# Installing Ruby 1.9 on OS X 10.6

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, installation, ruby

I'm attempting to install the latest stable version of Ruby (1.9.2) on OS X 10.6.4.

The installation was successful, but the 'ruby' command is still erroneously referencing the previous installation. I've removed the `ruby` symlink from `/usr/bin/` (left the installed frameworks alone). Here are the results of a few commands:

```
> which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby

> ruby --version
-bash: /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory

> /usr/local/bin/ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
```

I'm confused as to why `which ruby` and `ruby --version` seem to be referencing different file paths. I think I'm missing one basic step here. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a shell alias or function or something like that defined, that is invisible to `which` but which is called instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: I left the default ruby installation alone, just deleted the symlink, then navigated to the destination of the symlink to see what was there. When I was running my commands, I was still in the `ruby.framework` directory, so the call to `ruby --version` was referencing the local folder copy of ruby, not the one associated with `which`.

Comment: srsly? this is a desperate attempt to build rep

Comment: @aking1012 Of course not. It was a mysterious problem caused by a silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

add a soft link in /usr/bin for ruby is one solution...another is to make sure usr/local/bin appears first in your $PATH

Comment: to me, it looks like a slightly misconfigure mac port or an attempt to make the OS find 1.8 first if both are installed...alternately you could use rvm.  that's what i use to manage multiple concurrent ruby installs: http://www.blog.bridgeutopiaweb.com/post/how-to-install-rvm-and-rails-3-on-snow-leopard/

Comment: That's what I plan on doing. Any idea why `ruby` and `which ruby` are referencing different paths? I had always thought the would point to the same path.

Comment: which just looks for the file...ruby may have been compiled with a hard-coded location if some environment variables are not set namely $RUBY_HOME i think

Answer (score 1):

Best way to have multiple ruby version is to use [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/). after installing rvm you can install multiple ruby version simply by

```
rvm install 1.8.7
rvm install 1.9.2
rvm install jruby
```

switching is even more easy, type (in terminal)

```
rvm use 1.8.7 --default #to use rvm for this terminal session and also sets ruby 1.8.7 as default ruby version
ruby -v #should give ruby version set for current session
ruby use 1.9.2 #sets different ruby to be used for this session
```

for complete installation instruction see [here](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)